# ¡Winter Bash 2018!

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2018

El mundo esta lleno de tradiciones anuales muy interesantes. Por ejemplo, los eventos de lanzamiento de [tomates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Tomatina)  y [naranjas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Oranges), el [bufete para monos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_Buffet_Festival), y las [festividades donde se rueda el queso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper%27s_Hill_Cheese-Rolling_and_Wake). Con estos ejemplos de la creatividad humana, nosotros en Stack Overflow no quisimos pasar la oportunidad de tener una también. Hemos creado y mantenido nuestra propia tradición anual - ¡Winter Bash!

Este año, deseamos *tejer* a nuestros usuarios en nuestro amor hacia los sombreros por séptima vez. Y también hemos agregado una manera para que puedan practicar su creatividad sin gastar estambre real. Empezando hoy (12 de Diciembre) y hasta el final del primero de enero estaremos en la [temporada de Winter Bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La manera en que se pueden ganar estos sombreros es con completar ciertos desafíos en sitios participantes.  Estos desafíos darán la oportunidad de desbloquear sombreros que podrás usar en tu avatar por toda la red. También hemos modificado la selección de sombreros y hasta incluimos [algunos sugeridos por ustedes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help).  Algunos de los detonantes fueron actualizados….y sí ¡existen sombreros que vas a querer descubrir por ti mismo!

En cuanto obtengas un sombrero, podrás visitar tu perfil en cualquier sitio para escoger el artículo que quieras ponerte.  Simplemente haz clic en el sombrero que adorna la sección de medallas en tu perfil y verás el siguiente diálogo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto te llevará a la caja de sombreros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona un sombrero que hayas ganado y usa las herramientas para ajustar el tamaño y la orientación de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Y listo! Ahora puedes presumir tu colección de sombreros.

¿Por qué no usas un sombrero nuevo cada día de la semana? Esta a tu discreción - si los ganas, los puedes usar.  Pero, date cuenta que el 2 de enero los sombreros regresarán al almacén donde pasaremos el resto del año limpiando y reparando los que se rompieron o se ensuciaron.

¡Les deseamos mucha suerte y mucho gozo mientras se unen con nosotros otra vez para nuestra celebración anual!

Comment: ¿Podemos compartir lo que hemos _tejido_?

Comment: ¡Por supuesto! Si quieres, abre otra pregunta en Meta para poder lucir esa creatividad.

Comment: ¡Así lo haré! :)

Comment: ¡Épico! ¡Tradición de cada diciembre :D !