# ¿Tienes cabeza para usar sombrero? Llegó el Winter Bash 2018

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2018

**¡¡Ya está aquí el [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)!!**

> La presentación del evento en nuestra comunidad está en en este post:
>   [¡Winter Bash 2018!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3773/winter-bash-2018) donde se explica como conseguirlos y usarlos.

Como se ha hecho otros años ([2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/desfile-winter-bash-2017), [2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194/combinaciones-explosivas-avatar-sombrero-del-sumter-bash)) propongo que pongamos aquí los avatares con su sombrero que más nos llamen la atención. Los que más nos gusten, los más raros, los más feos, en definitiva: los más.

Todavía no he visto muchos pero uno que me ha gustado es este de **@abulafia** que parece que una serpiente "python" sale de una caja con un halo de misterio a su alrededor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Feliz temporada del sombrero, **¡hazte con todos!**

Comment: ¿Como se consiguen?

Comment: @JDev [¡Winter Bash 2018!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3773/22721)

Comment: @JDev realizando diferentes acciones, en el enlace que he puesto dice como se consigue cada uno: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/ Suele haber algunos ocultos también.

Comment: Estaría genial que aquí se comparta los sombreros y en la otra publicación lo que hemos tejido en la [página de Winter Bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/), así no mezclamos las cosas y mantenemos la tradición :)

Comment: Buena idea @KakosPro

Answer (score 9):

Existe el dicho no le den a un mono una hojilla... Yo diría no le den a @Trauma unos lentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi otro usuario logro evitar comer comida Chatarra con su hijo  es @gbianchi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo, y la imagen que podria ser el Fin para mi en el sitio ess  ...... Los Moderadores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Edicion #1:

Faltaba un moderador..... para que se uniera al lado del sombrero.... ahora si Bienvenido [@AlvaroMontoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro)

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Faltan sombrero faltan participantes, Espero llegar al final del 2018 por lo menos xD

Comment: ¡¡ Si es que salgo *guapo* me ponga lo que me ponga !! XDDD

Comment: me faltan sobreros para las otras dos cabezas  de mi foto de perfil

Answer (score 9):

Tomémonos un momento para apreciar la majestuosidad de nuestro único [JackNavaRow](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow) y su sombrero hecho a la medida

[image: Foto de perfil de JackNavaRow con sombrero rosado]

Comment: Soy todo una realeza

Answer (score 8):

A mi me ha hecho mucha gracia la de [Shaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/73/shaz)

[image: Shaz]

Y, aunque el autobombo esté mal, me gusta mucho cómo ha quedado la mía, una vez que una de las serpientes haya mutado en pato :-)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según [@JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow), eso ilustra el [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) de python :-)

Comment: HAHAHAHAAAAAAAAA xD!!!!!!!

Comment: A mi también para mí los dos buenos Robocop el y pablolozano

Comment: Parece que está así por el peso del casco XD

Answer (score 8):

Como ya se ha comentado a @Trauma todo le sienta bien pero creo que la chistera y el bigote le dan un toque de elegancia y distinción extra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡¡¡ Dios !!! ¡¡¡ **PERO QUE GUAPO SOY** !!!

Answer (score 7):

Todos hemos visto un camaleón, pero les aseguro que nadie ha visto un Mago Camaleón

Les presento a [Iván Montero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/86561/iv%c3%a1n-montero)

[image: Camaleón con un sombrero azul]

Y ahora que lo veo, los íconos del *Top(nav) hat* están en desorden

Answer (score 6):

A mi me gustó mucho el de [blonfu](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7176/blonfu) :D

[image: Imagen de perfil de blonfu con el casco de Robocop al revés]

Parece que su cabeza está en un [balde/cubo/cubeta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubo_(recipiente))

Comment: Se parece a uno de los integrantes de Daft Punk xD

Answer (score 4):

Gustarme el sombrero de otro usuario, el de trauma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por que junto con su imagen de perfil, parece una persona formal pero al mismo tiempo impactada por algo

ahora yo tengo este al momento en mi perfil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gusta por que:

1. Es el primer *winter bash* en el que estoy
2. En la cintilla tiene los íconos de algunas de las tareas que puedo realizar
3. Me gusta que uno de los controler te permite girarlo

Comment: A mi tampoco me disgusta, pero en principio el objetivo es poner los de otros usuarios que te hayan sorprendido/gustado :)

Comment: cierto @Pikoh :D

Comment: te diera -1 , me gustaba mas el @Trauma con los lentes retro!

Comment: @JackNavaRow Es lo que nos pasa a algunos, que **todo nos queda bien** XDDD ¿ Detecto algo de envidia ?

Comment: ¬¬ @Trauma te iba a aqgregar con los lentes, pero cambiastes de foto  :(

Comment: @JackNavaRow Solucionado :-) todo sea por salir **2 veces** aquí XDDD

Answer (score 2):

La verdad es que me siento mal por acaparar tanta atención ... soy de naturaleza humilde y tímida XDD

En justo agradecimiento, os presento la *imagen con sombrero* que mas me ha llamado la atención:

Observad esa aparente simplicidad, esa *semi*simetría, ese gorro tímidamente inclinado a la izquierda mientras que por abajo, apenas llamativa, vemos ese apéndice reclamando también un poco de atención, esa expresión apática, hastiado ya de que sean otros los que se lleven el mérito, los votos y los sombreros ...

¡ Veamos a [JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow) !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sabia que algo de envidea iba a dar sus frutos!

Comment: XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD