# No dejes para mañana, lo que puedas tejer hoy

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2018

¡Llegó el [Winter Bash](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3773/winter-bash-2018)! Y con ello vinieron [algunas tradiciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3774/tienes-cabeza-para-usar-sombrero) :)

Como lo menciona Juan M en el post, este año el tema es *tejer* y Stack Exchange nos ha [proporcionado un canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

[image: Imagen del canvas para tejer]

Al dar clic en *Start Knitting* tendremos un lienzo en blanco para desatar nuestra imaginación.

Sin mas preámbulo les presento a:

> [image: Wolf Constellation - una imagen con algo que trata de asemejarse a una constelación en forma de un lobo, una luna llena, un árbol y un muñeco de nieve]
>   **La constelación del Lobo**, únicamente visible cuando hay luna llena en el Winter Bash

**Si se sienten creativos compartan sus creaciones, si no ¡háganlo también! :D**

---

**FAQ**

- ¿Se vale tejer teorías de conspiración?

  - Si, aquí se respeta la libertad de expresión, pero debe ser en el canvas de la página.
- ¿Qué pasa si estoy tejiendo mi telaraña, pero luego viene la lluvia y se la lleva?

  - Tendrás que esperar que salga el sol, seque la lluvia y tejerla de nuevo
- ¿Cuál es la temática?

  - Tejer

Comment: Muy bueno ese dibujo.Yo intente hacer un círculo y conseguí una patata

Comment: Winter is coming!

Answer (score 8):

Aprovechando el borde curvilíneo..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: menuda currada!

Comment: ¡Qué gran resultado!, ¡me gusta!

Answer (score 7):

Saludos comunidad comparto el mío, el logo de SO en español, solo que en modo navideño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7):

Y aquí mi dibujo ^^

Felices fiestas a todos. Y portaos bien, que <strike>los moderadores</strike> Santa Claus vigila :P

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment:  *Te observan cuando duermes. Te miran al despertar. No intentes ocultarte de ellos. Pues siempre te verán. Los moderadores llegaron a la ciudad* 

Answer (score 6):

Dejo el mío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Picasso se queda corto

Comment: La "abstracción" no es lo mío ... :-(, saludos Emiliano!

Answer (score 5):

Yo con mi habitual [pareidolia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) sólo puedo ver al oso de la marca de joyería Tous (a ver si se estiran y me regalan algo por la publicidad...) así que no he podido resistirme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese oso tiene unas turgentes.... ;) Disculpad mi pareidolia

Comment: Que son los pies, degenerado!

Answer (score 3):

Esta es la [fuente original de la publicación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320073/271772) que hice en Meta.StackExchange.com

---

Esta fue la primera versión del personaje de *(Deltarune - creo que así se llama)*.

> yo le digo:   ***S  A  N  S***

[image: I hope it L I K E S Y O U]

---

Esta es una versión mejorada que hice *(sin usar alguna imagen de referencia)*.

> Solo conozco a este personaje por el tema de los **dank memes** xD

[image: I M P R O V I N G...]

Answer (score 2):

Lo unico que pude hacer es un sombrero Binario con mi color favorito, no es una obra de arte pero digamos que lo usaria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo lo utilizaría en un suéter navideño 

Answer (score 2):

Aquí el mío sin mucho que decir .

[image: Winter Bash]

Comment: es chulísimo :D