# ¿Qué han tejido en este Winter Bash?

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2019

Espero que hayan empezado el 2020 de la mejor manera.

Hice este post para que compartan sus tejidos, como lo hicieron en [2018](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3778/no-dejes-para-ma%C3%B1ana-lo-que-puedas-tejer-hoy)

Muestren sus obras de arte [empezar a tejer](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/),

*pd: Se me ha complicado un poco tejer sin mi color favorito (marrón)*

Answer (score 11):

No me tilden de machista, solo no hubo espacio para Mandy

[image: dibujo1]

Aquí hice lo que pude, mirandolo bien, hubiera borrado esa cosa amarilla

[image: Mario Bross]

Comment: :O me gusta ese mario, pero nunca vi un fantasma en un mundo de mario al aire libre

Comment: la idea principal era que mario este parado sobre la bala de cañón.. luego me quede sin espacio, por eso esta "¿flotando?" y donde esta el fantasma pensaba poner [esto](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/75/af/aa75afab7d18c787055eb61df2a8c0e8.png) jeje

Answer (score 10):

Hubiera sido genial si dejaran una paleta enorme de colores!

[image: Paisaje Winter Bash]